# show latest authors blog post

Tags: posts, loop, query-posts, author

how do you display the latest authors blog post?

I have the below code:

```
<?php
$author = get_the_author();
$args = array( 'numberposts' => '1', 'author'=>$author );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
}
?>
```

However the above code display the most recent post for all users instead of a specific user.

Comment: On which page is this

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This To Get Post in DESC order

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'author' =>'authorName',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query ->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query ->have_posts() ) {
        $query ->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Please Check This [Link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

I hope this will help you. 
have a good day :-)